# Get height of tab content on click?

Tags: jquery, click

How do I check the new height of tabbed content on click?

This is only working for the first tab content shown:

```
$(".tab-link").click(function(){
    var newHeight = $(".tab-content").height();
    alert(newHeight)
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` to get current tab height.

```
$(".tab-link").click(function(){
    var newHeight = $(this).height();
    alert(newHeight)
});
```